# Proving that for every $\lambda$ there exists an $x \in \mathbb R$ so that $x(p(x)-2)^2=\lambda$, where p(x) is a non-constant polynomial.

Tags: calculus, polynomials, proof-explanation

The question is:

Prove that for every $\lambda$ exists an $x$ such that $x(p(x)-2)^2=\lambda$, where $p(x)$ is a non-constant polynomial, and $\lambda \in \mathbb R$

So I've gone ahead and opened up the brackets:

$$x(p(x)^2-2(2)(p(x))-4))$$

Which simplifies down to:

$$ x*p(x)^2-4x*p(x)-4x=\lambda $$

Now I've gone ahead and picked p(x) to be a polynomial of degree n ($n \in N$), and  $ {a_n...,a_0} \in R $

$$ p(x)= a_nx^n +a_{n-1}x^{n-1}...a_1x+a_0   $$

First step is $p(x)^2$ which I got the folowing:

$$(a_nx^n +a_{n-1}x^{n-1}...a_1x+a_0)^2=2a_na_{n-1}x^{2n-1}+a_{n-1}^2x^{2n-2}+a_n^2x^{n+1} + 2a_na_1x^{n+1} + 2a_0a_nx^n +2a_{n-1}a_1x^n+2a_0a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+a_1^2x^2+2a_0a_1x+a_0^2   $$

Now the issue is: I'm missing tons of terms, and I have no idea how to continue since the order is also messed up. Is there a much simpler way to continue this proof? I feel like I'm missing something to solve this in a smaller # of steps...

Comment: I'm sure you mean something else, because this is not true. Consider $p(x)=x+2$, $\lambda=0$ and $x\not=0$.

Comment: I don't begin to understand this. How can $x(p(x)-2)$ possibly be a constant for $p(x)$ a polynomial (unless of course $p(x)$ is identically 2)?

Comment: @YourAdHere  sorry fixed the question. I need to prove that for every $\lambda$ that I pick, theres an x that fulfills the above

Comment: Then it is easy: $q(x)=x(p(x)-1)^2-\lambda$ is a polynomial of odd degree and therefore has a real zero (i.e. $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $q(x)=0$).

Comment: What are you allowed to use? The simplest argument is that $x(p(x)-2)^2-\lambda$ must be positive for large positive $x_2$ and negative for large negative $x_1$, so the intermediate value theorem tells you it must be zero for some value between $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: @YourAdHere how is it possible to formally prove it?

Comment: @almagest Use of the intermediate value theorem is allowed. Hmm didn't even think of that.. How would I continue with that?

Comment: @RonaldB So now write up your solution as an Answer, so we can check it and upvote it!

Comment: @almagest I'm still having difficulties with a start to the proof. Any additional hints?

Comment: from the intermediate value theorem we get that each polynomial of odd degree has x such that q(x) = 0. 
why? 
because lim (q(x)) = infinity when x goes to +infinity
and lim (q(x)) = -infinity when x goes to -infinity. 
hope this is clear